# Run c++ class from python

Tags: python, c++

Is there a way to **run a c++ class from python without using any external libraries** like Boost.Python, SWING ect? I don't want to pass any arguments to this class or call a specific method and in my c++ class I have only a void main method, I just want to run the main and that is all.

Or if this is not possible a saw this tutorial http://intermediate-and-advanced-software-carpentry.readthedocs.io/en/latest/c++-wrapping.html#manual-wrapping. But I didn't understand if I should put the hello_wrapper function in the same c++ class where I have the original hello function. And also how can I create a modulo in Python(second part in the tutorial) and where should I put this code

```
DL_EXPORT(void) inithello(void)
{
  Py_InitModule("hello", HelloMethods);
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> is there a way to run a c++ class

you don't run C++ classes. They are data types!

> Boost.Python, SWING

It's called SWIG, not SWING :)

You can add your own C wrapper code that initializes a PyObject. I'd recommend reading the CPython docs and the examples in the tutorial on extending python. Since you didn't specify a version, I can't give you a discrete link.

Note that python is C, and C++ isn't; which means that you'll have to export several things with a C ABI, i.e. by using `external "C"` in your code. That might not be something for the uninitiated, and you should certainly evaluate whether not using external wrapper generators is really worth the trouble – especially since using e.g. SWIG properly (which is really a pain) you can get Python objects that *really* behave like python objects, e.g. you can extend them with python etc.